# thinking sphinx not generating configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

Migrating an application to another server... upon `bundle exec rake ts:configure`
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ~/app/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf

sphinx.yml states

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
  searchd_file_path: ~/app/shared/sphinx
  use_64_bit: true
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1
  max_matches: 10000
  port: 9313
```

thinking_sphinx.yml states

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
  pid_file: ~/app/shared/tmp/searchd.pid
  configuration_file: ~/app/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf
  indices_location: ~/app/shared/sphinx
  use_64_bit: true
  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 2
  max_matches: 1000
  mysql41: 9313
  mem_limit: 128M
```

I fail to comprehend the message that states that `development.sphinx.conf` does not exist as it is supposed to be created from the rake task.

Comment: Does the ~/app/shared/config directory exist?

Comment: it sure does. And it contains the four files which are symlinked into app/current/config: database.yml  local_env.yml  sphinx.yml  thinking_sphinx.yml

Comment: on further thinking, I realised this was a new instance and possibly sphinx went uninstalled.  Still after `sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch`, re-deployment, ensuring gem file had thinking-sphinx. got same error.

Comment: Can you try changing it to an absolute path, instead of relative?

Comment: That seems to have been the problem.  I also realised I had not created the /app/shared/sphinx directory.  `ts:configure` runs, but `ts:index` hits `Generating configuration to /home/jerdvo/saim/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf
sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/indexer: not found`.  So I have not instaleld correctly...

Comment: should the sphinx.yml be pointing at `/etc/sphinxsearch` ? should a sphinx.conf be created there?  Not too certain as `http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/installing_sphinx/linux.html` does not state either way...

Comment: `/usr/bin` is the proper directory.  However indexing is returning '0' docs indexed, and `rake ts:start` returns `reload: failed to open /home/jerdvo/saim/shared/sphinx/document_core.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING`  which means the indexing is not running as it should...

Comment: Nailed culprit, but don't know how to fix:  a search revealed: `./home/mainuser/app/releases/20141111084349/shared/sphinx/staticpage_core.sph`  indices are going there, not in the shared directory. I don't see what is wrong with the indices_location listed in the initial answer below...

Comment: Which version of Thinking Sphinx are you using?

Comment: 3.0.3 is the version in the gem file

Comment: Okay, so it's worth noting that `config/sphinx.yml` is irrelevant (it's for TS v2 or older). Can you confirm indices_location is set up properly in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml`? And worth running ts:rebuild to ensure configuration has these changes applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64706/discussion-between-jerome-and-pat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two components to the answer:

1) make absolute paths
2) indexer on Ubuntu is at `/usr/bin`

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/bin
  pid_file: /home/mainuser/app/shared/tmp/searchd.pid
  configuration_file: /home/mainuser/app/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf
  indices_location: /home/mainuser/app/shared/sphinx
[...]
```

Answer is still partial as indexing captures 0 documents and no `.sph` file is generated.